# APEX substitution string disappearing

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, string-substitution, bind-variables

I'm running APEX 5.1 on ORACLE 12.1.

I have ca. 80 APEX similar applications running on the same database - each application is using the same substitution string :CLIENT_ID with its own value (storing a code name of the application). 
:CLIENT_ID is used through the "V" function: V('CLIENT_ID') all over the applications calling a shared framework of views and packages on the database.

Out of the sudden in one of the applications, one of the Interactive Reports fails with the exception that the :CLIENT_ID is not set. All other pages or similar pages in other applications work perfectly fine.

- Surprisingly, if I add a natural join with 1 row from dual it starts working fine! But only if it is natural join and only if I select a value of a function reading some other APEX substitution variable.
- If I change it by adding "natural join (select 1 from dual)" it keeps failing.
- recompiling the view that uses :CLIENT_ID does not help.
- running SQL forming a failing view does not help.
- some changes to the SQL forming a failing view help (but give wrong data so cannot be a solution)
- DBMS_RESULT_CACHE.FLUSH does not help
- ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH BUFFER_CACHE does not help
- ALTER SYSTEM FLUSH SHARED_POOL does not help

Can anyone give me any hint (except bouncing the database) what I could do to investigate more?

Comment: I've doubled "_query_execution_cache_max_size" but it needs a bounce to be applied

Comment: Very much the same problem occurs with the package variables. Shared package has some variables to store parameters for views. Every session is using that package, so has its own versions of the variables. Until, in some random place in random application, these variables are NULLified in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. The dynamic SQL is updating the table using views that use the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the explain plan changing over time. The root cause of the problem is described here: 
[When "PARTITION LIST SUBQUERY" is in the execution plan something (a bug?) de-instantiates the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50907322/when-partition-list-subquery-is-in-the-execution-plan-something-a-bug-de-in)

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the views are calling a function that is labeled `deterministic` when in fact the function is referencing `V('CLIENT_ID')` in the code; making it non-deterministic.

See [PL/SQL Function Definition](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/function.htm#LNPLS01322) and search for DETERMINISTIC, noting especially

> Do not specify DETERMINISTIC for a function whose result depends on the state of session variables or schema objects

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yes, we have DETERMINISTIC functions that are stable for every session (but return different things for every session, that's why DETERMINISTIC and not RESULT_CACHE is used) .

Comment: ... and YES, removing DETERMINISTIC from functions calling V('CLIENT_ID') removed the problem. I still believe it is only a workaround to the problem... I wish I knew why deterministic caching does not work as I'd expect it to.