# When "PARTITION LIST SUBQUERY" is in the execution plan something (a bug?) de-instantiates the package

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-execution-plan

Is this an Oracle 12c bug?

I run 64-bit Oracle 12.1.0.2 on Oracle Linux.
Came across a strange thing: when the execution plan switches to using  "PARTITION LIST SUBQUERY" then the package used in the affected query is loosing all of its variable's values. It looks like something de-instantiates the package just like after running DBMS_SESSION.RESET_PACKAGE.
The query uses a partitioned table which partitions are limited by joining with another table limited using a variable from the package read using a deterministic "getter" function.
**If I change the function not to be deterministic, or change anything so the explain plan is not using "PARTITION LIST SUBQUERY" the problem does not appear.**

See the synthetic example that produces the explain plan with "PARTITION LIST SUBQUERY" on my databases (tried on 4):

```
-- Clean-up ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE facts CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE DIM_CALENDAR CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP PACKAGE Parameters_PKG;

-- First, partitioned table  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE factS
( mth VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)    NOT NULL
, just_data VARCHAR2(120 BYTE)  NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST (mth)
(  
   PARTITION M01 VALUES ('M01')
,  PARTITION M02 VALUES ('M02')
,  PARTITION M03 VALUES ('M03')
,  PARTITION M04 VALUES ('M04')
,  PARTITION M05 VALUES ('M05')
,  PARTITION MAX_VALUE VALUES (DEFAULT)
    LOGGING
    ROW STORE COMPRESS BASIC
)
;
INSERT INTO facts SELECT 'M' || TO_CHAR(LEVEL, 'FM09'), STANDARD_HASH(LEVEL, 'SHA384' ) FROM dual connect BY LEVEL < 4;
COMMIT;

-- Second table to iterate the partitions of the first table ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE DIM_CALENDAR
(
  CLIENT_ID  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
  mth        VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)               NOT NULL
)
;
INSERT INTO DIM_CALENDAR SELECT 'TEST', 'M' || TO_CHAR(LEVEL, 'FM09') FROM dual connect BY LEVEL < 2;
INSERT INTO DIM_CALENDAR SELECT 'OTHER', 'M' || TO_CHAR(LEVEL, 'FM009') FROM dual connect BY LEVEL < 10;
INSERT INTO DIM_CALENDAR SELECT 'ANOTHER', 'M' || TO_CHAR(LEVEL, 'FM09') FROM dual connect BY LEVEL < 2;
COMMIT;

-- Analyzing both tables to get to the desired explain plan ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXECUTE DBMS_STATS.GATHER_SCHEMA_STATS (NULL, NULL);

-- A package with deterministic ffunction ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Parameters_PKG
AUTHID DEFINER
AS
   FUNCTION  get_Client_ID RETURN VARCHAR2 deterministic; 
   PROCEDURE Set_Client_ID (p_Client_ID     VARCHAR2);
END Parameters_PKG
;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Parameters_PKG
AS
   Client_ID  VARCHAR2(255);
FUNCTION get_Client_ID   RETURN VARCHAR2   
AS
   PRAGMA UDF;
BEGIN
   IF Client_ID IS NULL THEN 
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Fatal error.');
   END IF;
   RETURN Client_ID;
END get_Client_ID;
PROCEDURE Set_Client_ID (P_Client_ID VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
   Client_ID := UPPER(TRIM(p_Client_ID));
END Set_Client_ID;
END Parameters_PKG
;
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


-- The test ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- exec Parameters_PKG.Set_Client_ID('TEST') -- this should return 2 rows
exec Parameters_PKG.Set_Client_ID('wrong_value_to_have_0_rows_returned') 
SELECT Parameters_PKG.Get_Client_ID FROM dual; -- a check that the value is really set.

SELECT f.mth, f.just_data  
FROM facts f, DIM_CALENDAR c  
WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = Parameters_PKG.Get_Client_ID
AND F.mth = C.mth
;


/* Failing explain plan with  "PARTITION LIST SUBQUERY"

SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 43.194  Bytes: 336  Cardinality: 3              
 4 HASH JOIN  Cost: 43.194  Bytes: 336  Cardinality: 3          
  2 PARTITION LIST SUBQUERY  Cost: 43.107  Bytes: 303  Cardinality: 3  Partition #: 2  Partitions accessed #KEY(SUBQUERY)   
   1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE FACTS Cost: 43.107  Bytes: 303  Cardinality: 3  Partition #: 2  Partitions accessed #KEY(SUBQUERY)
  3 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE DIM_CALENDAR Cost: 87  Bytes: 44  Cardinality: 4    

*/
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. A reproducible test case would really help, though.

Comment: A reproducible test case is right above. It would be great to see if you hit the same issue on some other databases.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the 'deterministic' keyword.  DETERMINISTIC means for the same set of inputs I can return the same output without evaluating the function again.  You have *no* inputs to that function, so we never need to run it.  So we'll return null, eg (with your setup code omitted)

```
--
-- with deterministic
--
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Parameters_PKG
  2  AUTHID DEFINER
  3  AS
  4     FUNCTION  get_Client_ID RETURN VARCHAR2 deterministic;
  5     PROCEDURE Set_Client_ID (p_Client_ID     VARCHAR2);
  6  END Parameters_PKG
  7  ;
  8  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Parameters_PKG
  2  AS
  3     Client_ID  VARCHAR2(255);
  4  FUNCTION get_Client_ID   RETURN VARCHAR2
  5  AS
  6     PRAGMA UDF;
  7  BEGIN
  8     IF Client_ID IS NULL THEN
  9        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Fatal error.');
 10     END IF;
 11     RETURN Client_ID;
 12  END get_Client_ID;
 13  PROCEDURE Set_Client_ID (P_Client_ID VARCHAR2)
 14  IS
 15  BEGIN
 16     Client_ID := UPPER(TRIM(p_Client_ID));
 17  END Set_Client_ID;
 18  END Parameters_PKG;
 19  /

Package body created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> exec Parameters_PKG.Set_Client_ID('TEST')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT f.mth, f.just_data
  2  FROM facts f, DIM_CALENDAR c
  3  WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = Parameters_PKG.Get_Client_ID
  4  AND F.mth = C.mth
  5  ;
FROM facts f, DIM_CALENDAR c
     *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20001: Fatal error.
ORA-06512: at "MCDONAC.PARAMETERS_PKG", line 9


SQL>
SQL> exec Parameters_PKG.Set_Client_ID('wrong_value_to_have_0_rows_returned')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT f.mth, f.just_data
  2  FROM facts f, DIM_CALENDAR c
  3  WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = Parameters_PKG.Get_Client_ID
  4  AND F.mth = C.mth
  5  ;
SELECT f.mth, f.just_data
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20001: Fatal error.
ORA-06512: at "MCDONAC.PARAMETERS_PKG", line 9

--
-- without deterministic
--
SQL>
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Parameters_PKG
  2  AUTHID DEFINER
  3  AS
  4     FUNCTION  get_Client_ID RETURN VARCHAR2;
  5     PROCEDURE Set_Client_ID (p_Client_ID     VARCHAR2);
  6  END Parameters_PKG
  7  ;
  8  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Parameters_PKG
  2  AS
  3     Client_ID  VARCHAR2(255);
  4  FUNCTION get_Client_ID   RETURN VARCHAR2
  5  AS
  6     PRAGMA UDF;
  7  BEGIN
  8     IF Client_ID IS NULL THEN
  9        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Fatal error.');
 10     END IF;
 11     RETURN Client_ID;
 12  END get_Client_ID;
 13  PROCEDURE Set_Client_ID (P_Client_ID VARCHAR2)
 14  IS
 15  BEGIN
 16     Client_ID := UPPER(TRIM(p_Client_ID));
 17  END Set_Client_ID;
 18  END Parameters_PKG;
 19  /

Package body created.

SQL>
SQL>
SQL> exec Parameters_PKG.Set_Client_ID('TEST')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT f.mth, f.just_data
  2  FROM facts f, DIM_CALENDAR c
  3  WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = Parameters_PKG.Get_Client_ID
  4  AND F.mth = C.mth
  5  ;

MTH    JUST_DATA
------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
M01    C6537FE410CFA617AFE7F17E6DD72BD9A6EF9ED08CA1216A811320A31A1FE0F9E57D832061B1A7EAA3534D8473098CBF

1 row selected.

SQL>
SQL> exec Parameters_PKG.Set_Client_ID('wrong_value_to_have_0_rows_returned')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT f.mth, f.just_data
  2  FROM facts f, DIM_CALENDAR c
  3  WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = Parameters_PKG.Get_Client_ID
  4  AND F.mth = C.mth
  5  ;

no rows selected

SQL>
SQL>
```

And here is an alternative using a CONTEXT variable

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE factS
  2  ( mth VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)    NOT NULL
  3  , just_data VARCHAR2(120 BYTE)  NOT NULL
  4  )
  5  PARTITION BY LIST (mth)
  6  (
  7     PARTITION M01 VALUES ('M01')
  8  ,  PARTITION M02 VALUES ('M02')
  9  ,  PARTITION M03 VALUES ('M03')
 10  ,  PARTITION M04 VALUES ('M04')
 11  ,  PARTITION M05 VALUES ('M05')
 12  ,  PARTITION MAX_VALUE VALUES (DEFAULT)
 13      LOGGING
 14      ROW STORE COMPRESS BASIC
 15  )
 16  ;

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO facts SELECT 'M' || TO_CHAR(LEVEL, 'FM09'), STANDARD_HASH(LEVEL, 'SHA384' ) FROM dual connect BY LEVEL < 4;

3 rows created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE DIM_CALENDAR
  2  (
  3    CLIENT_ID  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE)              NOT NULL,
  4    mth        VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)               NOT NULL
  5  )
  6  ;

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO DIM_CALENDAR SELECT 'TEST', 'M' || TO_CHAR(LEVEL, 'FM09') FROM dual connect BY LEVEL < 2;

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO DIM_CALENDAR SELECT 'OTHER', 'M' || TO_CHAR(LEVEL, 'FM009') FROM dual connect BY LEVEL < 10;

9 rows created.

SQL> INSERT INTO DIM_CALENDAR SELECT 'ANOTHER', 'M' || TO_CHAR(LEVEL, 'FM09') FROM dual connect BY LEVEL < 2;

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> create context my_context using Parameters_PKG;

Context created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Parameters_PKG AS
  2     PROCEDURE Set_Client_ID (p_Client_ID     VARCHAR2);
  3  END Parameters_PKG;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Parameters_PKG AS
  2
  3  PROCEDURE Set_Client_ID (P_Client_ID VARCHAR2)
  4  IS
  5  BEGIN
  6     dbms_session.set_context('MY_CONTEXT','CLIENT_ID',UPPER(TRIM(p_Client_ID)));
  7  END Set_Client_ID;
  8  END Parameters_PKG;
  9  /

Package body created.

SQL> exec Parameters_PKG.Set_Client_ID('TEST')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> SELECT f.mth, f.just_data
  2  FROM facts f, DIM_CALENDAR c
  3  WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = sys_context('MY_CONTEXT','CLIENT_ID')
  4  AND F.mth = C.mth
  5  ;

MTH
------
JUST_DATA
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
M01
C6537FE410CFA617AFE7F17E6DD72BD9A6EF9ED08CA1216A811320A31A1FE0F9E57D832061B1A7EAA3534D8473098CBF


1 row selected.

SQL>
SQL> exec Parameters_PKG.Set_Client_ID('wrong_value_to_have_0_rows_returned')

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT f.mth, f.just_data
  2  FROM facts f, DIM_CALENDAR c
  3  WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = sys_context('MY_CONTEXT','CLIENT_ID')
  4  AND F.mth = C.mth
  5  ;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry if I sound harsh (I value your work at @askTOM). Yes, I understand deterministic and and no, that is not true (to what I read in the documentation). Deterministic functions need to be run once per server call (and this is the reason why the function was defined as deterministic). In the above synthetic example the function is hyper-simple but if it wasn't then removing deterministic will ruin the performance. If I change the explain plan, so it does not use partition list subquery  the deterministic function works like a charm.  I'm pretty sure I hit some bug...

Comment: In which case try WHERE c.CLIENT_ID = ( select Parameters_PKG.Get_Client_ID from dual ) as a caching workaround

Comment: Thanks Connor - I tried that too. It changes the explain plan to "partition list all", so works even with deterministic left on. I'm not good enough to change to "PARTITION LIST SUBQUERY" in the above synthetic test case, but I'd swear I was still getting the error in my real environment even when using scalar subquery caching. Would you be able to force "PARTITION LIST SUBQUERY" with ( select Parameters_PKG.Get_Client_ID from dual ) added?

Comment: Two things I'd do:
1) Why not use a context variable and avoid all the package execution/deterministic stuff altogether?
2) Test with larger data.  A 4 row fact table is likely to always scan all partitions...because its 4 rows.  I did an experiment with 4million rows in the fact (and a context) and got the expected bloom filter optimizations.

Comment: I tried with SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'CLIENT_INFO') and it worked OK - not sure if DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO is actually using context though.

I am not so keen on recoding using context as it seems to be rather complex.
The original Parameters_PKG handles three, session specific parameters reading from APEX V() functions and also using a dedicated table to allow local debuging (without APEX) and store parameters between sessions....

Well, this is not so interesting to you.. I'm just trying to describe my misery so you can maybe post the test you created using context.  Can you?